# In ChartJS is it possible to change the line style between different points?

Tags: chart.js

Using ChartJs (v2.2.2) can you change the line style between the last 2 points on a graph. e.g. have a solid line all the way and then dashed at the end? see picture below

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`borderDash`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-element-configuration)property  (*scroll to Line Configuration*) is the key to your problem.

The thing is, the full chart is drawn with a border dash, you cannot choose where it starts and where it ends.
A simple workaround is to create two identical datasets. One dotted and one with a plain line. Then you remvoe the last data of your plain one, and they both will be displayed as how you want it.

You can see the full code in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4m5dp17x/), and here is its result :

[image]

*Note :*

- Since there are two datasets now, the legend will display both of them. Setting the `display` to false fixes it (*more or less*).
- The declaration order doesn't matter since the plain line will always overwrite the dotted one.
- Having a bezier curve (`tension` property > 0) can create a display problem since the data is not the same in both datasets.

Comment: Thanks - I had a similar idea to yours (in fact the only difference is that my dashed dataset just has the last 2 points!)  I just wanted to check there was no way to do this out-of-the-box that I might have missed.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no built-in property to do this .. yet I hope

Comment: I have spend the last few hours poking around v2.1 and arrived at the same conclusion as @Tektiv. As far as I can see this is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `scatter` chart and draw the lines directly on the canvas using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). The API offers a range of hooks that can be used for performing custom code. The advantage of this approach is that you can customize the style of every single connection line (width, color, dash pattern etc.).

```js
const labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const values = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
const data = labels.map((label, index) => ({ x: label, y: values[index]}));

var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "scatter",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];      
      chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (index > 0) {        
           var valueFrom = data[index - 1];
           var xFrom = xAxis.getPixelForValue(valueFrom.x);     
           var yFrom = yAxis.getPixelForValue(valueFrom.y);   
           var xTo = xAxis.getPixelForValue(value.x);         
           var yTo = yAxis.getPixelForValue(value.y); 
           ctx.save();      
           ctx.strokeStyle = '#922893';
           ctx.lineWidth = 2;
           if (index + 1 == data.length) {
             ctx.setLineDash([5, 10]);
           }
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(xFrom, yFrom);             
           ctx.lineTo(xTo, yTo);
           ctx.stroke();
           ctx.restore();
        }
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: data,
      borderColor: '#922893',
      pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const values = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
const data = labels.map((label, index) => ({ x: label, y: values[index]}));

var lineChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "scatter",
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx; 
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-1'];
      var yAxis = chart.scales['y-axis-1'];      
      chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (index > 0) {        
           var valueFrom = data[index - 1];
           var xFrom = xAxis.getPixelForValue(valueFrom.x);     
           var yFrom = yAxis.getPixelForValue(valueFrom.y);   
           var xTo = xAxis.getPixelForValue(value.x);         
           var yTo = yAxis.getPixelForValue(value.y); 
           ctx.save();      
           ctx.strokeStyle = '#922893';
           ctx.lineWidth = 2;
           if (index + 1 == data.length) {
             ctx.setLineDash([5, 10]);
           }
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.moveTo(xFrom, yFrom);             
           ctx.lineTo(xTo, yTo);
           ctx.stroke();
           ctx.restore();
        }
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: data,
      borderColor: '#922893',
      pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).